# NullPointerException al momento de graficar con netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola solicito de su ayuda ya que tengo un error inesperado al momento de correr mi código, el cual me debe de crear una gráfica con los datos obtenidos de una base, eh estado buscando soluciones, en convertir valores, el mismo error persiste y nada alguien puede ayudarme en saber que me hace falta o que estoy haciendo mal o el por que de esa Exception.

Eh tratado de cambiar la conversión de valores y tampoco me funciona

```
     columna.addColumn("Semana");
     columna.addColumn("BD");
     columna.addColumn("BT");
     columna.addColumn("P");
     columna.addColumn("FJ");
     columna.addColumn("DP");
     columna.addColumn("TP");
     columna.addColumn("M");
     columna.addColumn("IE");
     columna.addColumn("PC");
     
      jTablaPant.setModel(columna);
     String[] datos = new String[10];
     try {
             Statement leer = conect.createStatement();
             ResultSet resultado = leer.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(ip_e01_bdelanteras), SUM(ip_e02_btraseras), SUM(ip_e03_pretina),SUM(ip_e04_falsojalera),SUM(ip_e1_delanterosp),SUM(ip_e2_traserosp),\n" +
"SUM(ip_ma_malternos),SUM(ip_es_inmisionentregada),SUM(ip_ee_produccioncompleta)FROM inmision_pant WHERE YEARWEEK(fecha) = '202301';");
             
             while (resultado.next()){
             datos[0] = resultado.getString(1);
             datos[1] = resultado.getString(2);
             datos[2] = resultado.getString(3);
             datos[3] = resultado.getString(4);
             datos[4] = resultado.getString(5);
             datos[5] = resultado.getString(6);
             datos[6] = resultado.getString(7);
             datos[7] = resultado.getString(8);
             datos[8] = resultado.getString(9);
             datos[9] = resultado.getString(10);
             columna.addRow(datos);}
     } catch (Exception e) {
     }
     double dato1 = Double.parseDouble(datos[1]);
     double dato2 = Double.parseDouble(datos[2]);
     double dato3 = Double.parseDouble(datos[3]);
     double dato4 = Double.parseDouble(datos[4]);
     double dato5 = Double.parseDouble(datos[5]);
     double dato6 = Double.parseDouble(datos[6]);
     double dato7 = Double.parseDouble(datos[7]);
     double dato8 = Double.parseDouble(datos[8]);
     double dato9 = Double.parseDouble(datos[9]);
     
     Datos.addValue(dato1, "02/05/2023", "BD");
     Datos.addValue(dato2, "02/05/2023", "BT");
     Datos.addValue(dato3, "02/05/2023", "P");
     Datos.addValue(dato4, "02/05/2023", "FJ");
     Datos.addValue(dato5, "02/05/2023", "DP");
     Datos.addValue(dato6, "02/05/2023", "TP");
     Datos.addValue(dato7, "02/05/2023", "M");
     Datos.addValue(dato8, "02/05/2023", "IE");
     Datos.addValue(dato9, "02/05/2023", "PC");

grafica = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Produccion diaria",
"Días", "Cantidad", Datos,
PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, true, false);
```

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
```

Comment: dentro del while, pon **System.out.println( resultado.getString(1) );** y verás porque no puede convertirlo el double.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)